# Get account features

Tags: android, accountmanager

I make a custom account in my app and I need add some string information to this account and want to get this information in other app, how can I add and get some feature to account?

create account :

```
AccountManager accountmanager = AccountManager.get(A);
Account aaccount[] = accountmanager.getAccountsByType(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
if (aaccount.length == 0) {
    addNewAccount(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS);
}else{
    aaccount = accountmanager.getAccountsByType(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
}
```

Comment: If you just want to store some extra data with the account object, you can use the `setUserData` method on AccountManager: [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)